# Pages 12.0 on Monterey 12.4: Why can't I add or change certain parts of styles?

Tags: pages, monterey, formatting

See screen shots. All the circled options are greyed out.

File is not locked or read only.  I can edit text and other things no problem.

If it's relevant, collaboration is turned on and shared with one other person, who has same versions of everything. I'm the owner, sharing to him.

2021 M1 Max MBP.
Monterey 12.4.
Pages 12.0.

Does anyone have any idea why those items are greyed out, and I can't add or change them?

Thanks!

---

[image: Paragraph Styles]

[image: List Styles]

[image: Following Paragraph Style]